# JavaScript - declaring get property in object literal

Tags: javascript

I came across the following JS object declaration:

```
var myObj = {
  calc: function calc() {
    return 'calc method';
  },
  get name() {
    return 'test name property';
  }
};
myObj.name// -> 'test name property'
```

I understand what 'calc: ..' is but what is 'get name'? Is this some new syntax for declaring 'get' property? Cannot find it in documentation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: oh, thanks for right direction.